# evaluating an expression using values

Tags: python

I am trying to evaluate the following expression (exp). I'm trying to replace var[i] in exp by values[i] and evaluate the expression and would really appreciate some help. I have tried re.subs and replace however it isn't working.

```
exp='((2*3.14)/(550*12))*((R*F*L)/t)'
var=['R','F','L','t']
values=[1202,10.12,15.63,60]
```

It should output: ((2*3.14)/(550*12))*((1202*10.12*15.63)/60)= 3.016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the value for `each var` is at the same index in the `values` list
You can just replace a variable with the corresponding value in `values` list to the `exp` string

```py
exp='((2*3.14)/(550*12))*((R*F*L)/t)'
var=['R','F','L','t']
values=[1202,10.12,15.63,60]
for i,j in zip(var, values):
    exp = exp.replace(i, str(j))
```

**Output**:

```
>>exp
'((2*3.14)/(550*12))*((1202*10.12*15.63)/60)'
```

You can call `eval` function to evaluate the value.

```
>>eval(exp)
3.0151464826666667
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! the most straightforward answer

Comment: You can accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `f-string` with named values and format it with a dict

```
exp = "((2*3.14)/(550*12))*(({R}*{F}*{L})/{t})"
var = ["R", "F", "L", "t"]
values = [1202, 10.12, 15.63, 60]

valdict = dict(zip(var, values))
print(valdict)
filled = exp.format(**valdict)
print(filled)
print(eval(filled))
```

Which produces

```
{'R': 1202, 'F': 10.12, 'L': 15.63, 't': 60}
((2*3.14)/(550*12))*((1202*10.12*15.63)/60)
3.0151464826666667
```

Of course if you are the one building the `var/values`, you should skip the two lists and build the `valdict` directly, which makes it a lot more readable.

And if you want to print only three decimal digits use

```
print(f"{eval(filled):.3f}")
```

Which prints `3.015` and not `3.016` as you request, but it should be the right value.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you have only such simple variable names (single letter), then the following will be enough:

```
expr = '((2*3.14)/(550*12))*((R*F*L)/t)'
var = ['R','F','L','t']
values = [1202,10.12,15.63,60]
for n,v in zip(var, values):
     expr = expr.replace(n,str(v))

print(f'{expr} = {eval(expr):.5f}')
```

Set format specifier to the desired one or remove it.

If you have more complex variables names, try using sympy. Example:

```
import sympy
var = sympy.symbols('R F L t')
values = [1202,10.12,15.63,60]
expr = sympy.sympify('((2*3.14)/(550*12))*((R*F*L)/t)', evaluate=False)
with sympy.evaluate(False):
    num_expr = expr.subs(zip(var, values))
print(f'{num_expr} = {num_expr.doit():.5f}')
```

Can't get rid of printed '*1/', but you can just remove it by hands:

```
...
print(f'{num_expr} = {num_expr.doit():.5f}'.replace('*1/','/'))
```